# error deleting items from listview

Tags: asp.net

Hi,

I have a problem here. I got a datatable which the data is display in listview. here is the behind code function.

```
Protected Sub ListView1_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewCommandEventArgs)
        If (e.CommandName) = "Sort" Then
            Dim txteno As Label = DirectCast(e.Item.FindControl("lblID"), Label)
            /* Error here Dim deletecommand As String = "delete from dt where ID=" & Convert.ToInt32(txteno.Text)
            Session("dt").DeleteCommand = deletecommand
        End If
    End Sub
```

The things is when I press the delete button an error occur saying "Input string was not in a correct format." Anyone knows what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by

`Convert.ToInt32(txteno.Text)`

and that the value of `txteno.Text` is not a valid integer.

What is the value of `txteno.Text` when you attempt to run the code?

As a workaround, use `Integer.TryParse` instead.

```
Dim number As Integer

If Integer.TryParse(txteno.Text, number) Then

 ' Do the delete....
End If
```

Comment: its value is "". I have some inkling of this problem but no idea how do solve. In the deltecommand, i need to specify the table name but the trouble is the data in the table is sometihng i receive from the users which mean the sqldatasource is the datatable. My question is how do i declare the datatable's table name in the listview?

Comment: Exactly. Breakpoint in that line and check what is the real value of `txteno`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you can not access to `e.Item.FindControl` from the `ListView_ItemCommand` method.

The `FindControl` only works on rendering time, ie, in the `ListView_ItemDataBound` method.

One possible solution is to retrieve the item from your list or directly from your database. For this, you can use `e.Item.DataItemIndex` to retrieve the id of the row.

Comment: i coundnt find the command e.item.dataitemindex in the list of command available.

Comment: Are you trying to access it (it's not a "command", it's an atribute) from inside `ListView_ItemCommand` method? I'm not assuming... it exists :P -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2974236/asp-listview-how-do-i-access-the-data-that-is-databound-to-the-rows